# Ionic native app rate not working for android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I am Building multiple ionic apps, app rate option in other apps perfectly but in one app its not showing app rate prompt even. My app rate function looks like following

```
    rate(){
    this.appRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
      // ios: '',
      android: 'market://details?id=app_id',
      // windows: 'ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=<store_id>'
    };

    this.appRate.promptForRating(true);

    // or, override the whole preferences object
    this.appRate.preferences = {
      usesUntilPrompt: 3,
      storeAppURL: {
        // ios: '<app_id>',
        android: 'market://details?id=app_id',
        // windows: 'ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=<store_id>'
      }
    };
    this.appRate.promptForRating(false);
  }
```

and html code is

```
<button ion-button color="vibrant" (click)="rate()"><span style="color:#e2c767">Rate App Now</span></button>
```

Comment: How can by pass prompt for rating? Is it open playstore url?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add other configuration settings. I committed the same mistake that you have inadvertently made. Include the following code in the constructor,

```
appRate.preferences = {
    storeAppURL: {
      ios: '<app_id>',
      android: 'market://details?id=<package_name>',
      windows: 'ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=<store_id>'
    },
    customLocale: {
      title: 'Do You Enjoy?',
      message: 'Please Rate Us',
      cancelButtonLabel: 'No Thanks',
      laterButtonLabel: 'Remind me later',
      rateButtonLabel: 'Rate It Now',

    },
    callbacks: {
      onRateDialogShow: function (callback) {
        console.log('dfcsd');
      },
      onButtonClicked:function(buttonIndex){
        console.log('Selected Index is '+buttonIndex);
      }
    },
    simpleMode:true
  }
```

Add the full configurations settings including the callbacks and customLocale as evident from the code above. And then finally, in the rate() function,

```
 this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although I not sure why, having storeAppURL alone is not prompting the rate popup and will not navigate to the App Store (I tested only on iOS)

Comment: Having partial configuration causes malfunctioning of the app and shows a white screen. Full configuration makes app function properly but no option is presented to users to rate the app. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

What language is your device set to?

There is currently a bug in the plugin if your device is set to any language other than English or Portuguese. I have opened an issue here and added possible solutions: https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/218

PS: I'm assuming that the code after `// or, override the whole preferences object` is commented out when you test it. Because otherwise, you have 2 `promptForRating` calls in the same, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Language is english.

Comment: Is this your exact code you are running? Try removing the second part where you have duplicated code. And make sure you use the right link to your app and not app_id. Maybe also add a `console.log()` to make sure your rate function is actually called.

Comment: function is being called properly, id is also accurate and this is the exact code i am using.

Comment: Why do you set `this.appRate.preferences` and call `promptForRating` twice?